# Get friendlist from Facebook with FBRequest

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to read friendlist from Facebook and show in TableView but I haven't any reaction. My delegate's peace of code:

```
    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"user_location",
                    @"friends_location",
                    @"read_friendlists", 
                    nil]; 
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
    [permissions release];
    }
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

`request:didLoad` method look like:

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
_contacts = result;
}
```

`contacts` it's my instance NSArray what I want to fill with contacts from Facebook. In `tableViewController` I've done next thing:

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    cell.textLabel.text = [appDelegate.contacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

In result I have not any in my tableView. I am interested in what I am doing wrong? I'm generally do in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure, that this result is instance of NSArray, not NSDictionary? I'm playing with fb iOS SDK right now, and got NSDictionary as a result of same request. The dictionary has two key-paths: 'data' (contains NSArray with desired friends) and 'paging'.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But question is actually closed. Thanks you)